# How can I better understand and appreciate curling?

Tags: strategy, tactics, curling

I have watched many curling matches (games? I'm honestly not sure of the terminology) during coverage of the olympics. I have read the basic rules, which seem simple enough, so I understand the mechanics.

However, I feel like I am missing most of the strategy and theory of the game. Where/how can I better appreciate curling?

Comment: This is not constructive. It is way too vague. Ask about something specific rather than a general understanding of the entire sport.

Comment: I am sorry this question is closed, but here you can find some info http://www.curlingschool.com/ about this wonderful sport

Comment: I think asking info about a sport strategy/tactics is not a vague question. I hope the question it will be re-opened

Comment: @Ale As waxeagle says, asking about something **specific** in regards to the sport of curling would make this a much better question. Asking about strategy/tactics isn't the issue here...the issue is asking a question that is open-ended and too broad.

Answer (score 2):

With beer!  If you thought baseball needed beer to get through a game, you ain't never tried curling! Curling is much better with beer!

However, on a more serious note, I would suggest you try playing it.  It is a lot harder and more fun than it looks.  Especially if you like running, slip-sliding, up and down a sheet of ice then you will enjoy curling.

Most rinks will have plastic tape that you cover your sliding foot with, and then any average pair of shoes will work, with your uncovered foot acting as a pusher, and your covered foot used for sliding.

I suck at it, but it is really a lot of fun trying.

Getting the stones to stop in the right place is very hard, but still doable.

The sheet level perspective is worth it, if you want to better understand the game.

Comment: any sport is better with beer, unambiguously!